# Using MaxMind java class with ColdFusion

Tags: java, coldfusion, railo, maxmind, lucee

I'm trying to use MaxMind java library with ColdFusion.

I start converting this sample code on official MaxMind site:

```
// A File object pointing to your GeoIP2 or GeoLite2 database
File database = new File("/path/to/GeoIP2-City.mmdb");

// This creates the DatabaseReader object, which should be reused across
// lookups.
DatabaseReader reader = new DatabaseReader.Builder(database).build();

InetAddress ipAddress = InetAddress.getByName("128.101.101.101");

// Replace "city" with the appropriate method for your database, e.g.,
// "country".
CityResponse response = reader.city(ipAddress);

Country country = response.getCountry();
```

What I've tried is:

```
var file = "pathto\maxmind\GeoLite2-City.mmdb";
var db = createObject("java","java.io.File").init(file);

var mm = createObject("java", "com.maxmind.geoip2.DatabaseReader")
.Builder(db)
.build();

dump(c);abort;
```

I got this error:

```
Type: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException 
Messages: No matching Method for Builder(java.io.File) found 
for com.maxmind.geoip2.DatabaseReader
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Side note, 'file' is a reserved word in CF so you might want to choose a different variable name to avoid inadvertent issues.

Comment: Yes, I have posted the code on the fly, as an example only. My real code it's a bit different. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(**Update:** [@oschwald already provided the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35822980/104223). However, I am leaving this as an extended comment as it contains some helpful details about accessing inner classes and constructors from CF)

> `DatabaseReader reader = new DatabaseReader.Builder(database).build();`

Notice the `.` in the new class name statement? That indicates Builder is a special type of class. It is a nested or [inner class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) of DatabaseReader, so you need to use a special syntax to create an instance of it, ie `createObject("java", "path.OuterClass$InnerClass")`.

Also, `new DatabaseReader.Builder(database)` calls a constructor of the Builder class to create a new instance. CF does not support the "new" keyword with java objects. Instead, use the [psuedo method `init()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec14231-7fdd.html#WSA2304DF9-11E3-4e19-BA9A-3B12B0D6FA03) to call the constructor:

```
var mm = createObject("java", "com.maxmind.geoip2.DatabaseReader$Builder").init(db).build();
```

**NB:** Calling `init()` explicitly is only required when invoking a [class constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html) with one or more arguments, as is the case here. If the java code was instead using the default, no-argument constructor ie `new DatabaseReader.Builder().build()`, you could technically omit the call to `init()`. CF automatically invokes the no-argument constructor if needed, when the first non-static method - ie `build()` -  is invoked.

Comment: Nice explanation. Definitely more complete than mine. :-)

Comment: @oschwald - Thanks. Though I see from your profile you are definitely the more knowledgeable resource to tap for questions about the inner workings of MaxMind :)

Answer (score 2):

`Builder` is a class, not a method. Perhaps try something like:

```
var mm = CreateObject("java", "com.maxmind.geoip2.DatabaseReader$Builder").Init(db).build();
```

Comment: Drat.. beat me by five seconds! +1 ;-)

Comment: ... could have sworn the "$" was not there the first time around though ;-)