# Jsoup in CFscript execute connection as POST

Tags: coldfusion, jsoup, cfml, coldfusion-11

The page I want to parse could be get only by POST method.

This is easy for Java as I can see:

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
Response res = Jsoup.connect("URL").method(Method.POST).execute();
Document doc = res.parse();
```

I could not produce the same thing using CFscript.

```
jsoup = createObject("java", "org.jsoup.Jsoup");
response = jsoup.connect("URL").method(Method.POST).execute();
if (response.statusCode() == 200)
{
    doc = response.parse();
}
```

-ERR Element POST is undefined in METHOD

I tried almost everything.
I was unable to use .method() and .execute() at the same time.

If I call .get() or .post() directly I can not check statusCode() back then.

Comment: Why was this down voted? It contains a clear example, error message and describes the issue and how they tried to solve it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the API, [Method](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Connection.Method.html) is another JSoup class. You need to create an instance of that class before you can access the [POST](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Connection.Method.html#POST) constant.  Also, Method is a little different than your typical java class. It is an [enum](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) (or constant). Those are essentially handled as inner classes, which [require a special syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35822549/using-maxmind-java-class-with-coldfusion/35822981#35822981) with createObject:

```
methodClass = createObject("java", "org.jsoup.Connection$Method");
response = jsoup.connect("http://example.com").method(methodClass.POST).execute();
```

Comment: Works! That special syntax hint. Thank you!

Comment: That is a GREAT tip Leigh. Do you have a blog?

Comment: @MarkAKruger - I used to :-)  While I have known about inner class syntax for a while, I am sure I am not the first one to mention it. I would be extremely surprised if Raymond Camden, et.al. had not beaten me to it  ;-)

Comment: @leigh Doesn't matter - you should still do it. Let me know if you ever want to guest on mine, I'd be happy to let you.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can invoke the `post()` method directly:

```
response = jsoup.connect("URL").post();
```